# Time Series Analysis- ARIMA interpretation

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection

I have the graphs of ACF and PACF. But I am unable to interpret how to consider whether it is AR(p) or MA(q) or ARIMA. Along with ACF and PACF. ADF and PP test suggests that the data is Stationary.
Please Help me. Auto.arima() function suggests two models.But one of my friend suggested that one cannot blindly believe auto.arima() function.
[Figure 1 gives information about ACF and PACF of original Data]
[Figure 2 gives information about ACF and PACF of differenced with 1]
[image][image]

What does these signify?

Comment: Perhaps estimate AR(3) and check for auto-correlation in your residuals? And often theory should guide whether you should first-difference your data or not rather than formal unit root tests.

Comment: how many datapoints do you have?

Comment: @TPArrow I have 13data points.

Comment: @ Matthew Gunn I dont know the theory behind that. I just have to forecast the wages in this case.

Comment: @ Mathew Gunn.  Thank you very much for your reply. I don't know any thing about theory behind that. I am supposed to forecast using the past 13 data points.

Comment: 13  is not enough to make a right decision about the model. Forecasting is even worse with 13. However, I recommend you either increase the number of datapoints or report the results with the standard error (to make it clear enough),

Comment: @ Mathew Gunn I am very new to Statistics. Please help me how to check auto correlation in residuals  .

Comment: @visnu_statistics I suggest you ask you last question in comment as a new question on this site, and link to the above question.